# how to keep methods separate which are common in all the python test suit

Tags: python, automation, appium

Say suppose this is the python file, **androidChess.py**:

```
import os
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class ChessAndroidTests(unittest.TestCase):
    "Class to run tests against the Chess Free app"
    def setUp(self):
        "Setup for the test"
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.2'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Android Emulator'
        # Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
        desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'apps/Chess Free.apk'))
        desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'uk.co.aifactory.chessfree'
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.ChessFreeActivity'
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)

    def tearDown(self):
        "Tear down the test"
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_single_player_mode(self):
        "Test the Single Player mode launches correctly"
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_name("PLAY!")
        element.click()
        self.driver.find_element_by_name("Single Player").click()
        textfields = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("android.widget.TextView")
        self.assertEqual('MATCH SETTINGS', textfields[0].text)

#---START OF SCRIPT
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(ChessAndroidTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

I have **setup()** method which is **common in most of the files**. Instead of writing the same code in all the files, How can I **separate it** ? and call it from elsewhere ?

```
 def setUp(self):
            "Setup for the test"
            desired_caps = {}
            desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
            desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '4.2'
            desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Android Emulator'
            # Returns abs path relative to this file and not cwd
            desired_caps['app'] = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'apps/Chess Free.apk'))
            desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'uk.co.aifactory.chessfree'
            desired_caps['appActivity'] = '.ChessFreeActivity'
            self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

I want this function to be separate, and later shall be called from that location.
How to do this ? **Please help..**

Comment: i doubt you are simply looking for inheritance OR may be instantiating a class in another (http://www.jesshamrick.com/2011/05/18/an-introduction-to-classes-and-inheritance-in-python/)

Comment: I want to create a library file where I can store the modules that are common in most of the files.. Not just only the `setup()`, even other functions that are common..

Comment: are you seeking how to create a module/package in python(http://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages)? it seems like this is not related to appium, is it?

Comment: no.. not related to appium.. But the during the running of test, appium automation framework will be used..

Comment: Sorry, its not "modules", it should have been functions.  Just now i came to know that modules in python are nothing but a file with .py extension

Comment: can I place `setup()` in one module ?? and  import it from multiple modules ??

Comment: though i am not much aware of the `unittest` acess in python, you shall be able to access it.

Comment: I will try working on it.. and then come back to you.. :)